# subscribe to multiple platform event channels at once

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, html, platform-event

I am following [lightning/empApi example](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-emp-api/documentation) to subscribe to a Platform Event (PE) channel. I am able to successfully subscribe to one channel, but I cannot subscribe to multiple channels at once. I am using `LWC` and not any `aura` component.

**Questions**

1. How can I subscribe to multiple channels at once?
2. What would be the proper way to subscribe using empApi?

**Example code**

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import {
    subscribe,
    unsubscribe,
    onError,
    setDebugFlag,
    isEmpEnabled,
} from 'lightning/empApi';

export default class EmpApiLWC extends LightningElement {
    channelName = ['/event/Test__e', '/event/AnotherPE__e'];
    isSubscribeDisabled = false;
    isUnsubscribeDisabled = !this.isSubscribeDisabled;

    subscription = {};
    // Handles subscribe button click
    handleSubscribe() {
        // Callback invoked whenever a new event message is received
        const messageCallback = function (response) {
            console.log('New message received: ', JSON.stringify(response));
            // Response contains the payload of the new message received
        };

        // Invoke subscribe method of empApi. Pass reference to messageCallback
        subscribe(this.channelName, -1, messageCallback).then((response) => {
            // Response contains the subscription information on subscribe call
            console.log(
                'Subscription request sent to: ',
                JSON.stringify(response.channel)
            );
            this.subscription = response;
            this.toggleSubscribeButton(true);
        });
    }
}
```

**Error message**

> "400::The channel specified is not valid {/event/Test__e,/event/AnotherPE__e}"

**What I tried, but didn't work**

```
subscribe(JSON.stringify(this.channelName), -1, messageCallback).then((response) => {...}
```

Comment: @identigral no -- it refers to links that have moved and I am not using `cometD`. I am not using `Aura` component, strictly `LWC`. Any thoughts on how else to properly subscribe to multiple channels using `LWC` and `empApi`?

Comment: I think it fairly clear you need to iterate through the channel names and subscribe to each in turn. The [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-emp-api/documentation) clearly states that the channel given to subscribe is a string, not a string array. Each subscription will need to be stored in the component separately too, but arrays and JavaScript object properties are good for that sort of thing.

Comment: @PhilW for my understanding, I need to use a `for loop` to iterate through each value in the array and then call subscribe within the loop in order to subscribe to multiple channels? In doing so I could pass a string to the `subscribe()` method

Comment: Sounds right to me. Just make sure to store the subscriptions appropriately, not just the last one received.

Comment: @PhilW that worked like a charm, I added the sample code that worked for me as an answer.

Comment: Glad it worked for you and, more specifically, that you worked it out yourself from some hints. Always best because you learn more deeply.

Comment: BTW you could use `this.channelName.forEach(...)` to do the iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @PhilW as I was able to find a solution. I have to iterate through all possible channels to subscribe to and then subscribe in a loop.

```
for(let i = 0; i < this.channelName.length; i++) {
    subscribe(this.channelName[i], -1, messageCallback).then((response) => {...}
}
```